# Как отследить отключение Bluetooth устройства?

Tags: android

Недавно начал заниматься программированием под android. Возникла задача в приложении отслеживать изменение состояния удаленного устройства Bluetooth. Каким образом это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про BroadcastReciever.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html
https://habrahabr.ru/post/149875/